# When I insert some data it is inserted x times

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am working on a chat application. And when I send message or retreive it (using socket)  I save it to my embedded database and then show it to user. And when I am opening the chat activity for the first time everything works fine. But if I re-open chat activity for second or third... time it inserts message two or three ... times respectively. For example:

[image]

first time opened chat activity everything works fine

[image]

chat activity opened for third time and if I send message it is cloned to 3 messages

[image]

chat activity opened for 6th time and if I send message it is cloned to 6 messages

For 2 days I tried to solve the problem but no result. Also searched on the internet.No result

Here is the code of chatbox acitvity :

```
 socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                        try {
                            String room = data.getString("room");
                            String nickname = data.getString("senderNickname");
                            String message = data.getString("message");
                            String receiverNickname = data.getString("receiverNickname");

                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            contentValues.put(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGES_ROOM, room);
                            contentValues.put(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE_SENDER, nickname);
                            contentValues.put(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE_RECEIVER, receiverNickname);
                            contentValues.put(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE, message);
                            database.insert(DbItems.DbValues.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

                            chatBoxAdapter.swapCursor(getAllItems());

                            myRecylerView.setAdapter(chatBoxAdapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
private Cursor getAllItems(){
        return database.query(
                DbItems.DbValues.TABLE_NAME,
                null, null,
                null, null,
                null, null
        );
    }
```

And code of chatbox adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ChatBoxAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(holder.itemView.getContext()).getUser();
    String myEmail = user.getEmail();
    if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)){
        return;
    }
    String room = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGES_ROOM));
    String senderName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE_SENDER));
    String receiverName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE_RECEIVER));
    String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbItems.DbValues.MESSAGE));
    if (room.equals(message_room)){
        if (senderName.equals(myEmail)){
            holder.message_right.setText(message);
            holder.message_right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            if (receiverName.equals(myEmail)){
                if (!email.equals(senderName)){
                }else {
                    holder.message_left.setText(message);
                    holder.message_left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.message_user_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String url = "http://192.168.1.111/ulgamda_iuhd/uploads/" + senderName + ".jpg";
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(url)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile)
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .resize(604, 604)
                            .into(holder.message_user_image);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor){
    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.close();
    }
    cursor = newCursor;
    if (newCursor != null){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mike M, what kind of info do you need?

Comment: We don't know, really. We have no idea where or how you're using those snippets you've shown. You'll start to see what is necessary when you begin putting together your [mcve].

Comment: @Mike M. ok I wiill post my full code

Comment: @MikeM. added more code

Comment: I do not have any errors when it is working

Comment: And I can not access database folder to see where I am having trouble when I insert  data or when I get

Comment: One of the reason might be the primary key. Have you assigned the primary key for each and every message? @White

Comment: By looking at the picture we can say it's showing the duplicates @White

Comment: @g.brahma Datta yeah exactly it is dupliacting messages according to how many times I entered the chat activity and if I close my app it starts from beginning

Comment: I can not understand why it is duplicating messages

Comment: you can keep as "TEXT UNIQUE" when you are creating the table in the database where you are getting the repeated messages. You can avoid duplicates with this.

Comment: @ g.brahma Datta yes I can but some messages can not be unique

Comment: if it was email or mob number I could make it unique but messages can be repeated more than one time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192671/discussion-between-g-brahma-datta-and-white).

Comment: In that case, make the message id unique.you would have allocated separate id for different message right? @White